# In GDB how do I get globals' addresses

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have some globals that I want to inspect.  but "info var my_global" doesn't show the address.  is there a way to get the real address of the globals?

Answer (score 2):

`print &my_global` should work fine.  A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 12;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Then build & debug:

```
$ make example
clang -g    example.c   -o example
$ gdb example
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f04: file example.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: example 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done

Breakpoint 1, main () at example.c:8
8     printf("%d\n", x);
(gdb) print &x
$1 = (int *) 0x100001068
Current language:  auto; currently minimal
```